# Can I call CBPeripheral writeValue:forCharacteristic:type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse multiple times?

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I need to write different values to a single characteristic very quickly. I'm using

```
[cbPeripheral writeValue:myData forCharacteristic:myCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse]
```

Since I'm using WithoutResponse, I can't utilize a callback to know when it's safe to fire off another write.

I'm fine if some writes don't make it to the peripheral, but I do not want data corruption. Will the Core Bluetooth framework guarantee there's no data corruption, maybe in the form of writing to a buffer while it's in use?

Thanks!